# Keycloak is not saving data in PostgreSQL in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to run keycloak in docker and to save its data in PostgreSQl.
But nothing is being saved.

this is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    build: "./Main Database Backup"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_PASSW}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak-postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSW}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak:
    build: "./Keycloak Realm Export"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-postgres
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSW}
      POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: keycloak-postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Dockerfile in for `keycloak`

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:3.4.3.Final

WORKDIR /opt/jboss/keycloak

COPY realm-export.json initial_data.json

# RUN ./bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=initial_data.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING

RUN ./bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -r master -u admin -p password

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/initial_data.json"]
```

That `db` is the main database which is for my API and its working correctly.
While the `keycloak-postgres` is the database for keycloak and its not saving any data.

Also I have created a database in that server with the same name as ${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE} and I have created a user and gave all privileges to that server, so it wont be a permission error.

And I have provided all the environment variables correctly.

Also regarding to commented code in `keycloak` Dockerfile, I'm trying to import a realm which is not working.

When I'm commenting that `POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR` in `docker-compose.yml` its throwing this error:

```
2018-08-31T08:22:05.251344638Z 08:22:05,250 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2018-08-31T08:22:05.251375320Z     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
2018-08-31T08:22:05.251383320Z     ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
2018-08-31T08:22:05.251402169Z ]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression 'jdbc:postgresql://${env.POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR}:${env.POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT:5432}/${env.POSTGRES_DATABASE:keycloak}'"
```

Comment: How do you build the keycloak image? Which keycloak version? Read the docs to setup the KC 4 image with postgress, it should be enough to set the `DB_VENDOR` parameter: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: @XtremeBiker just added the Dockerfile of `keycloak`. Also I did try to add that DB_VENDOR=postgresql but still the same. Take a look at updated question, and see the error thats throwing when I'm commenting that env `POSTGRES_POST_5432_TCP_ADDR`

Comment: `DB_VENDOR` works only for KC 4 image: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml

Comment: @XtremeBiker now I point keycloak image to 4.1.0 version, and i added that `DB_VENDOR=postgres` but still not working

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @XtremeBiker referencing to that file from github if i make only keycloak and its database works great (with these 2 services), but when im trying to add that third service: db (application database), its throwing an error that says Couldnt connect to database

Comment: @XtremeBiker what i did was to just change the port of keycloak postgres to 5435, beucase maybe it was a conflict while they both was pointed to 5432. Also if you have any idea, why when I restart containers all data is cleared, its like its overwriting all the database when I'm running containers after restarting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't Keycloak related, it's more Docker container related (and postgres). Each time you stop a container you going to loose your data.

What you need to use is Volumes ... meaning. Map a driver on your PC to the docker container. Such that each time the container starts again it uses this drive therefore able to retain data. You need something along the lines of:

```yml
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    build: "./Main Database Backup"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_POSTGRES_APP_PASSW}
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: What I did was to change the port of keycloak-postgres to `5432` and that error is not showing anymore. While regarding to loosing data, thats exactly what i did (using volumes)